# Firebase function is not realtime(?)

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I have firebase function(javascript node.js) in flutter app. This function is creating the firebase collection of "timelineLocal" using the data based on "post" collection and "user" collection.

What I want is calling all the post from all the user and locate at the timelineLocal, but my function only calls the new post, not the old one. What am I missing? any help?

- users -> userID -> data field user
- timelineLocal-> userID -> "timelinePosts" ->  data field
- posts-> userID-> "userPosts" -> posted ->  data field

Here are the code

```
const functions = require("firebase-functions");
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();


exports.onCreateDistance = functions.firestore.document("/users/{userId}")
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        console.log("Follower Created", snapshot.id);
        const userId = context.params.userId;

        // 1) Create users posts ref
        const userPostsRef = admin
            .firestore()
            .collection("posts")
            .doc(userId)
            .collection("userPosts");

        // 2) Create user's timeline ref
        const timelinePostsLocalRef = admin
            .firestore()
            .collection("timelineLocal")
            .doc(userId)
            .collection("timelinePosts");

        // 3) Get users posts
        const querySnapshotLocal = await userPostsRef.get();

        // 4) Add each user post to user's timeline
        querySnapshotLocal.forEach(doc => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                const postId = doc.id;
                const postData = doc.data();
                timelinePostsLocalRef.doc(postId).set(postData);
            }
        });
    });


exports.onDeleteDistance = functions.firestore.document("/users/{userId}")
    .onDelete(async (snapshot, context) => {
        console.log("Follower Deleted", snapshot.id);
        const userId = context.params.userId;

        const timelinePostsLocalRef = admin
            .firestore()
            .collection("timelineLocal")
            .doc(userId)
            .collection("timelinePosts");

        const querySnapshotLocal = await timelinePostsLocalRef.get();
        querySnapshotLocal.forEach(doc => {
            if (doc.exists) {
                doc.ref.delete();
            }
        });

    });

exports.onCreatePostLocal = functions.firestore.document('/posts/{userId}/userPosts/{postId}')
    .onCreate(async (snapshot, context) => {
        const postCreated = snapshot.data();
        const userId = context.params.userId;
        const postId = context.params.postId;

        //1) get all the user who made the post
        const usersRef = admin.firestore().collection('users');
        const querySnapshotLocal = await usersRef.get();



        //2) Add new post to each user's timeline

        querySnapshotLocal.forEach(doc => {
            const userId = doc.id;

            admin.firestore().collection('timelineLocal').doc(userId).collection('timelinePosts').doc(postId).set(postCreated);
        });



    });


exports.onUpdatePostLocal = functions.firestore.document('/posts/{userId}/userPosts/{postId}').onUpdate(
    async (change, context) => {
        const postUpdated = change.after.data();
        const userId = context.params.userId;
        const postId = context.params.postId;

        //1) get all the user who made the post
        const usersRef = admin.firestore().collection('users');
        const querySnapshotLocal = await usersRef.get();

        //2) update  new post to each user's timeline
        querySnapshotLocal.forEach(doc => {
            const userId = doc.id;

            admin.firestore().collection('timeline').doc(userId).collection('timelinePosts').doc(postId).get().then(doc => {

                if (doc.exists) {
                    doc.ref.update(postUpdated);
                }
            });
        });



    });



exports.onDeletePostLocal = functions.firestore.document('/posts/{userId}/userPosts/{postId}').onDelete(
    async (change, context) => {
        const userId = context.params.userId;
        const postId = context.params.postId;


        const usersRef = admin.firestore().collection('users');
        const querySnapshotLocal = await usersRef.get();

        //2) delete  new post to each user's timeline
        querySnapshotLocal.forEach(doc => {
            const userId = doc.id;

            admin.firestore().collection('timeline').doc(userId).collection('timelinePosts').doc(postId).get().then(doc => {

                if (doc.exists) {
                    doc.ref.delete();
                }
            });
        });



    });
```

Comment: You have a lot of `doc.exists` checks inside you `querySnapshotLocal.forEach` calls, these are unnecessary as `doc.exists` will always be `true` for a [`QueryDocumentSnapshot`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot).

Comment: Your code also has 7 different lines that have an unhandled `Promise` (results/errors aren't handled) and many of these are in loops meaning you could have hundreds of these. Have a look at [this article](https://web.dev/promises/), [this video](https://youtu.be/DHvZLI7Db8E) and [this video](https://youtu.be/V_Kr9OSfDeU) to refresh yourself on how they work and how to handle parallel promises properly.